# Packing ironpython app into .exe and Installer

Tags: .net, python, ironpython

I'm not using sharpdevelop or visual studio for ironpython app development. I have my reasons for not using them for app development. What are my console based options for compiling ironpython .exe file and packaging it manually ?

Is it possible to create executable app with ironpython and pack it using installer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used pyc and InnoSetup to create my installers.  You can also download and run WIX from the command line without using #Develop or Visual Studio. The key is make sure you include all of the DLL's you need and to NGEN them on install for shorter start times and better performance.

Comment: Pardon my noobi question but how will you decide the require dlls other than the external ones you add ? any specific from the package itself needed for distribution ?

Comment: Add in and install the ironpython assemblies: IronPython.dll, IronPython.Modules.dll, Microsoft.Dynamic.dll, and Microsoft.Scripting.dll;  I usually create my own dll of the standard library, IPStdLib.dll; and the dll for my program created by pyc.py.  My WIX file references all of these runs the NGEN process on them during the install step.

Answer (score 3):

I use `IronPython\Tools\Scripts\pyc.py` to create .exe and then xcopy deployment instead of installer.